# iOS: what is the equivalent of an event listener in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, ios5

In some of my learning I saw someone mention that in your view controller you can have a model and have some sort of listener on the model for changes in it.  I don't think I'm using the right names for these, which is probably why my searches haven't turned up anything.  Essentially I want to move my server calls from the controllers into my models, but I need some sort of listener on them to know when the call is complete to update my views.

Comment: Take a look at [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html) by Apple.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

look into delegates
[delegates tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm)

or blocks a bit more advanced
[basic blocks tutorial](http://maniacdev.com/2011/07/tutorial-objective-c-blocks-closures-for-beginners/)

just start with delegates,

you can also use NSNotification [NSNotification tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_nsnotificationcenter/) but is not recommended as it broadcast to every class, and you might only need to send messages to a specific class not every one

Comment: I believe what I read was about the NSNotification, the reason I was leaning towards that is because I want the Model to be unaware of or uncaring about what was listening.  When I've implemented delegates in other places I needed to know about the delegate so I could call a specific method on it.

In this case I want to model to just broadcast that it finished, so whichever view might be listening for it can act in whatever way is appropriate for that specific view.

Comment: first link broken

Comment: Broken link, should be https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm (trailing "/" should be removed)

Comment: @manuelBetancurt seems the "basic blocks tutorial" is not available anymore. The website seems lost.

Answer (score 13):

Belong to C# world, i have to go to objective c (for my job). 
I think the event equivalent in objective c is this implementation :

Create protocol with all your event's methods :

```
@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)myEvent;
@end
```

In your class which should send the event, add :

```
@interface MyClassWichSendEvent : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet id<MyDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Raising the event where you want, for example :

```
- (IBAction)testEvent:(NSButton*)sender
{
    [self.delegate myEvent];
}
```

Now in your listener class, you should listen the events like this :

Add the protocol to your class that listening

```
@interface Document : NSDocument<MyDelegate>
```

In the implementation, on init or in interface builder, you must link delegate of your object instance to listen with self of your class which listen.

In code

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    myObjToListen.delegate = self;    
}
```

- In Interface Builder -> IBOutlet from delegate to your listen's class.

And finally, implement your method in your listener class :

```
- (void)myEvent
{
    NSLog(@"i have listen this event !");
}
```

Sorry for my english, i hope that help people who went from java or C#.

Comment: What I don't understand how do you call myEvent on an id? Because what I see is that delegate is an IBOutlet  id<MyDelegate>. Can you please explain a bit in details? Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for KVO - key/value observing:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

http://nachbaur.com/2011/07/29/back-to-basics-using-kvo/

Delegates + Notifications are good for communicating between objects but they don't automatically send msgs when a value changes (which from your question, that is what you are asking about)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for NSNotificationCenter which is a way to pass messages to whoever may be listening. So you can send out a notification from an event in your model and just listen for it in your controllers. A cleaner method might be to implement your own protocol with delegates.

Answer (score 0):

Objective C uses [delegates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)

This post has a nice example: [How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)